# What does '-L $path' mean in bash

Tags: bash

What does `-L $package_path` mean or do in the following code?

```
PACKAGES=(a b c)
COLORS=(32 33 34 35 36 32)
PACKAGE_LINK_PATHS=(false false false false false false)
SECONDS=0

esc=$(printf '\e')
for index in "${!PACKAGES[@]}"
do
    package_name="${PACKAGES[$index]}"
    package_path="node_modules/somewhere/${package_name}"
    color_code="${COLORS[$index]}"
    if  [ -L $package_path ]; then
        if [ $unlinkPackages = true ]; then
            printf "Unlinking ${package_name}\n"
        else
            # Cache the currently linked package path
            PACKAGE_LINK_PATHS[$index]=$(readlink $package_path)
        fi
        rm -rf $package_path
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ -L
```

means "test for symlink".

The  `printf "Unlinking ${package_name}\n"` is a big clue ;)

And `man bash` explains it too (search for -L):

```
-L file    True if file exists and is a symbolic link.
```

Comment: I have tried to verify in the bash, but this is what I got:
```➜  exec bash |
bash-3.2$ -L node_modules |
bash: -L: command not found
```

Comment: @LushaLi The command being used is `[` rather than `-L`. The `[` command accepts various tests, of which `-L` is one. See the output of `help [` and `help test` (run in bash) for details.

Comment: @LushaLi that is not how that works.  `man bash` and what Eliah stated `help [` will show what [ does. -L is just a code for link (symlink)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot.@Eliah Kagan and Rinzwind
When designing the bash, why do we use "[ ]" in bash? Won't wrapping the expression with "( )" be enough?

Comment: Well... that was a design decision by the creator. Bash is old. Probably [ and ] where not used for anything back then.